# How can I paste from excel to many inputs?

Tags: jquery

The purpose of the JavaScript code below is to enable the user to copy multiple cells at once from excel (rows & columns) and then paste them into multiple text inputs, so every cell is copied to the following input.
That code works well - http://jsfiddle.net/vqa8feL4/2/.

However I have two problems:

- Since I placed the text inputs in a table, the code stopped working, and I just can't figure out why.
- I want the code to make the pasted content go also into the *textareas* and not only to the text inputs.

With table: http://jsfiddle.net/vqa8feL4/1/

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
$('input').bind('paste', null, function(e){
    $this = $(this);

    setTimeout(function(){
        var columns = $this.val().split(/\s+/);

        var i;
      var input =  $this  
        for(i=0; i < columns.length; i++){
             input  .val(columns[i]);
            input = input.next();
        }
    }, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://api.jquery.com/next/

jQuery.next() looks for *the immediately following sibling of each element*

Since you've added the inputs to a td there are most likely no siblings.

You would need to get the current input then traverse up to the td then goto the next td and find the input contained.

```
input = input.closest('td').next('td').find('input');
```

However then you will run into trouble because if you're at the last td you need to traverse to the next tr (row) in the table.

here is a fiddle that might help you.

```
$('input,textarea').bind('paste', function (e) {
    var $start = $(this);
    var source

    //check for access to clipboard from window or event
    if (window.clipboardData !== undefined) {
        source = window.clipboardData
    } else {
        source = e.originalEvent.clipboardData;
    }
    var data = source.getData("Text");
    if (data.length > 0) {
        if (data.indexOf("\t") > -1) {
            var columns = data.split("\n");
            $.each(columns, function () {
                var values = this.split("\t");
                $.each(values, function () {
                    $start.val(this);
                    if ($start.closest('td').next('td').find('input,textarea')[0] != undefined || $start.closest('td').next('td').find('textarea')[0] != undefined) {
                    $start = $start.closest('td').next('td').find('input,textarea');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                     return false;  
                    }
                });
                $start = $start.closest('td').parent().next('tr').children('td:first').find('input,textarea');
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

Forgot the link to the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/cav8h5d1/